# Pandas: How to extra only latest date in pivot table dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

How do I create a new dataframe which only include as index the latest date of the column 'txn_date' for each 'day' based on the pivot table in the picture? 
Thank you

[image: Pivot Table of time series]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d1 = pd.to_datetime(['2016-06-25'] *2 + ['2016-06-28']*4)
df = pd.DataFrame({'txn_date':pd.date_range('2012-03-05 10:20:03', periods=6),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'day':d1}).set_index(['day','txn_date'])

print (df)
                                B  C  D  E
day        txn_date                       
2016-06-25 2012-03-05 10:20:03  4  7  1  5
           2012-03-06 10:20:03  5  8  3  3
2016-06-28 2012-03-07 10:20:03  4  9  5  6
           2012-03-08 10:20:03  5  4  7  9
           2012-03-09 10:20:03  5  2  1  2
           2012-03-10 10:20:03  4  3  0  4
```

**1.**

I think you need first [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) if necessary first, then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by level `day` and aggregate [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
df1 = df.sort_index().reset_index(level=1).groupby(level='day').last()
print (df1)
                      txn_date  B  C  D  E
day                                       
2016-06-25 2012-03-06 10:20:03  5  8  3  3
2016-06-28 2012-03-10 10:20:03  4  3  0  4
```

**2.**

Filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.duplicated.html):

```
#if necessary
df = df.sort_index()
df2 = df[~df.index.get_level_values('day').duplicated(keep='last')]
print(df2)
                                B  C  D  E
day        txn_date                       
2016-06-25 2012-03-06 10:20:03  5  8  3  3
2016-06-28 2012-03-10 10:20:03  4  3  0  4
```

Comment: glad can help! And one small advice to future - [Don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). good luck!